# jquery replace text with image, help

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
("*").each(function () { 
   if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
       $(this).text($(this).text().replace('basketball','test')); 
   } 
});
```

i'm only able to change the text to another string of text, but how can I pass an image?

Comment: All I want to do is replace all occurrences of basketball, with an image.

Answer (score 7):

```
("*").each(function () { 
   if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
      var newHTML = $(this).html().replace('basketball','<img src = "image.jpg" />');
      $(this).html(newHTML);
   } 
});
```

**EDIT**

My mistake. I thought you wanted to replace the entire element. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: This replaces the entire element, which isn't what he wants.

Comment: @SLaks isn't that what he wants? I might have misread the question. @ben where do you want to put basketball?

Comment: He wants to replace words within the text.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the `html()` rather than the `text()`.

You can simplify your code to

```
$("*").filter(function() { return !$(this).children().length; })
      .html(function(index, old) { return old.replace('basketball', '<img ... />'); });
```

Comment: @Ben: Sorry; my `filter` condition was inverted (it was selecting elements _with_ children).  Try again now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend [JQIR](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/jQIR/) for this. first replace `"basketball"` with `"<span class="jqir">basketball</span>"` as you are doing above. Then run the following:

```
$(".jqir").jQIR("png", "images/");
```

This assumes that you have an image images/basketball.png. You can adjust as needed.

Comment: There's no point in that.  Once you're injecting markup, you might as well inject actual images.